# Is it possible to add MacOS app from a Xcode project to Launchpad?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

Made a simple macOS app for personal use and was wondering if there's a way to add the project app to the Launchpad instead of having having to run the app through Xcode simulator.

Since we're able to install apps from Xcode to our iOS units I was hoping there was a way to do the same for a Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Open the Xcode project for the app that you want. Make sure that the target for your build is "My Mac". Then click `Product`→`Archive`. Once a new window opens with your archive, click `Distribute App`, then `Copy App`. Click `Next` then choose a location for the app to be put.

*Note: you can skip this if you pay for a developer's account (I think).* Next, right-click the app file and click `Open`. It will say it's from an untrusted developer (you) because you don't pay for the developer's program.

Now move the app into the Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, GO to `Product`→`Archive`→`Distribute App`→`Copy App` and move to application folder.